# Bokeh with Big Data in Millions

Tags: python, bokeh

My problem is I am getting large amounts of data from HIVE (around 10 million points). Bokeh alone is not capable of handling it. I tried below using Datashader. But I'm having trouble saving my image:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import datashader as ds
import datashader.transfer_functions as tf

conn = pyodbc.connect("xxxxxxxx", autocommit=True)
df = pd.read_sql("select devalue,fevalue,type from tblbigdata limit 10;",con=conn)
conn.close()

cvs = ds.Canvas(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

agg = cvs.points(df, 'devalue', 'fevalue', ds.mean('fevalue'))
img = tf.shade(agg, cmap=['lightblue', 'darkblue'], how='log')
img.save("out.png")
print("Done")
```

Getting Error:
`AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'save'`

Comment: Found solution for this. --->

from PIL import Image
---------
---------
Image = img.to_pil()
Image.save("C:\MyPython\myimage123.bmp","BMP")

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete code.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import datashader as ds
import datashader.transfer_functions as tf
from PIL import Image

conn = pyodbc.connect("xxxxxxxx", autocommit=True)
df = pd.read_sql("select devalue,fevalue,type from tblbigdata limit 10;",con=conn)
conn.close()

cvs = ds.Canvas(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

agg = cvs.points(df, 'devalue', 'fevalue', ds.mean('fevalue'))
img = tf.shade(agg, cmap=['lightblue', 'darkblue'], how='log')
Image = img.to_pil()
Image.save("C:\MyPython\myimage123.bmp","BMP")
print("Done")
```